# Installing a dimmer to control multiple lights

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture, dimmer-switch

I recently asked a [question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/62796/is-my-cl-dimmer-compatible-with-my-light-switch-fixture) about installing a dimmer and got a great reply. Now I want to install another dimmer, but this one might be tricky.

In our hallway there are three lights that are all simultaneously controlled by 3 light switches. 
[image]

I want to replace one of the 3 light switches with a dimmer so I could use that to dim the lights and the other 2 switches could just remain normal on off switches. Is this possible?

Here is the dimmer I want to use and its instructions:
[image]
[image]

I opened up one of the light switch fixtures and this is what I got:
[image]
[image]

So I have four wires going from the switch directly into the fixture. Looking at the instructions I can see what to do if there are 3 wires, but I have four. Can this work and if so how do I hook er up?

EDIT: Ok I read more about this and found that in this kind of setup there should be two 3-way switches and one 4-way switch. It looks like I opened up the 4-way switch right? So does that mean if I open up one of the other switches it will be a 3-way?

Comment: There are different kind of switches. So we would need a picture of the back side of the switch to see which cable is connected to which 'port'. (The 'ports' should be labeled btw)

Comment: Yes, that appears to be the 4-way. Both of the other switches should be 3-way, and have only 3 wires (plus maybe ground) attached.

Comment: Ok I guess I can figure it out from here. I might post a pic of the 3-way switch and just confirm how to proceed before hooking it up.

Comment: What is the make and model of the dimmer?